# Bayesian statistics: Can a posterior probability be exactly 1?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

I have a question regarding bayesian statistics. Is it possible to end up with a posterior probability of 1, that a slope is positive?

My likelihood data shows a greatly significant relationship, with a p-value of 0.000715. But does it make sense that I end up with a posterior probability of 1?

And do you know a smart way to calculate the posterior probability of a positive slope?

Comment: Exactly how did you compute this posterior probability?  Was it based, perhaps, on a Monte-Carlo method or is the calculation an exact analytical one?

Comment: And I suppose we are to assume that this p-value corresponds to a positive point estimate?

Comment: @conjugateprior: Yes, that is correct. The corresponding point estimate is 0.64.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, i used a MCMC to compute my posterior. I ended up with the result of 1, by identifying all of my iterations above 0.

Comment: That means you have an *estimated* posterior probability of $1$. As in all simulations, this value is uncertain. Unless the prior assigned zero probability to negative slopes, mathematically there must be some positive posterior probability of a negative slope--but your simulation just hasn't gone on long enough to detect that.

Comment: You ended up with the result that, after taking several thousands of samples from the joint posterior, the number of times that particular coefficient was non-positive was 0?

Comment: Assuming the sampler had converged then a larger sample will most likely turn up a negative slope, knocking that estimate off 1.  The smaller the posterior probability of that, the longer you'd have to wait, naturally.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am now trying to run another simulation with 1000000 iterations with thin=5. How would you compute the posterior probability of a posterior with a positive slope? Is there a simple way to calculate this?

Comment: Whether an analytical solution can be developed depends on your model and your prior, but you haven't disclosed any of that information.

Comment: You may run 10⁶ or 10⁹ iterations and still find a probability of one and still be unable to decide whether or not this estimate equal to 1 corresponds to a posterior probability of exactly 1. Simulation cannot help you with this question.

Comment: This Q seems answerable, IMO. In fact, I think a useful answer already exists amongst the comments here.

Comment: Like @gung I'm loathe to suggest this question be closed. However, I have a slightly different issue: the inclusion of "And do you know a smart way to calculate the posterior probability of a positive slope?" is essentially unconnected from the main point about whether the posterior probability can equal 1. As such I'm inclined to close as too broad. Once narrower in scope, I agree with gung that there can be an answer, even if it is of the "explaining a misconception" type.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that you're doing some sort of linear regression.) The only way you could end up with a posterior probability of 1 that the slope is positive is if either

1) the prior is zero for non-positive slopes, or
2) the likelihood is zero for non-positive slopes.

That's a straightforward consequence of Bayes' Rule.